# canvas how to move rect using arrows

Tags: javascript, canvas

I started learning canvas today, I started off creating a simple rectangle,
I need to make this rectangle move using the arrow keys, but the moveTo function doesn't seem to do anything, how can I achieve this.
This is my code so far

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="250" style="border:1px
        solid black;">
        </canvas>

     <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.fillStyle = "green";

        var x = 50,y=5,w=100,h=100;
        context.fillRect(x,y,w,h);

        document.onkeydown = function move()
        {
            switch(window.event.keyCode)
            {
                case 37:
                {
                    //left
                    context.moveTo(x++,y);
                    break;
                }
                case 38:
                {
                    console.log('up');
                    break;
                }
                case 39:
                {
                    console.log('right');
                    break;
                }
                case 40:
                {
                    console.log('down');
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
     </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't move rectangles around the canvas after you've drawn them with fillRect.

The canvas is just an image, so your rectangle becomes an unmovable shape painted on the canvas.

To "move" shapes, you must clear the canvas and redraw the shape in a new position.

BTW, context.moveTo is a path command that tells the context to move its drawing pen to your specified location.  It does not move an existing shape on the canvas.

For example, in your keyhandler when responding to left-arrow key:

- change the x coordinate leftward: x--;
- clear the canvas: context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
- redraw the rectangle at its new position: context.fillRect(x,y,w,h);